# Google Maps Places Autocomplete search any position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, autocomplete, maps, google-places-api

When I use google places autocomplete api and as search places with keyword

> &input=MyWord

result is places that start with MyWord. e.g.  MyWord1 , MyWord2, MyWordblalba
I want to get results that contain MyWord in middle or at any position of result. e.g. blabla**MyWord**bla

Is it possible ? I can't find any parameter or wildcard in documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not such functionality to search locations by wildcards, you can only search by beginning of the word

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Search functionality of the API, rather than Autocomplete. Autocomplete is designed to complete place names typed by an end-user and therefore focuses on generating suggestions for suffixes.